# Two different solutions to implicit ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Where is the gap in my Logic? Im trying to solve the following implicit first order differential equation: $$y=y'^2x+y'^2$$ so I make the substitution $$p=y' \Rightarrow p=\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial p}p'=p^2+(2px+2p)p’$$. Then after solving the linear differential equation we get that: $$p=1+\frac{c}{\sqrt{x+1}}=y’$$ So if we integrate  $p$ then we get:  $$y=x+2c\sqrt{x+1}+c'$$ where we have two parameters. But if we instead choose to plug $p$ in the original equation we get the answer:  $$y=(\sqrt{x+1}+c)^2$$Why the first metod yields infinitely many more solutions?

Answer (score 2):

By derivation (i.e. $p'$) you introduce more degrees of liberty, that you need to reduce by plugging the solution into the original equation.

I don't really get what you are doing with your partial derivatives though. Anyway just derivate the initial ODE gives:

$y'=(x+1)2y'y''+y'^2\implies 1=(x+1)2y''+y'$ after simplification by $y'$

Which solves to $y=c_1\sqrt{x+1}+x+c_2$ and effectively plugging into original ODE gives $c_2=1+\frac 14{c_1}^2$

And the initial solution is $(\sqrt{x+1}+\frac 12c_1)^2$ as you stated.

Comment: I introduced $p=p(x)=y'$ so took the derivative $\frac{dy(x,p(x))}{dx}$. Then got  a first order differential equation for $p(x)$ that I could solve. And sice $p=y'$, I just integrated it and got the solution with the two constants. I don't understand what's the difference between the two methods. How does one reduce the degrees of freedom?